# Using jQuery UI Autocomplete with datasource and 3d array php/SQL query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, user-interface, autocomplete

I want to use jQuery UI Autocomplet to make a form field autocomplete grabbing the values from a database:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

I have copied the code accross, but the example (birds) is an associative array.

```
$items = array(
"Great Bittern"=>"Botaurus stellaris",
"Little Grebe"=>"Tachybaptus ruficollis",
"Black-necked Grebe"=>"Podiceps nigricollis",
"Little Bittern"=>"Ixobrychus minutus");
```

etc etc

I want to query my database taking two fields, id and author.
However the query returns an multidimensional array, where each returned row from the database is an array.

```
e.g.  ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [Author] => Higgins ) ) ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 2     [Author] => Darl) )( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [Author] => Lewis) )
```

How can I return the query so it is in the format:

```
"1=>Higgins,
2=>Darl,
3=>etc etc,"
```

so that i can use the script?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your database array is `$dbresult`, you can do it like this:

```
foreach($dbresult as &$arr) {
    $completearray[$arr['ID']] = $arr['Author'];
}

var_dump($completearray);
```

above will output the following array:

```
1=>Higgins
2=>Darl
3=>Lewis
```

**UPDATE**: I've updated the code above so the resulting array is indexed by the ID field.

Comment: Hi Nelson
the problem is I have two fields coming from each row in the query result (ID and Author)

I want the resulting array to be
ID=>Author
so that the id matches up to the author id

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code in my answer to reflect that, try it and let me know.